# some background Images not shown on page refresh (F5)

Tags: image, ssl, browser-refresh

When I refresh the login page some of the background images are not visible. Sometimes it happens to none, and sometimes to 1, 3 or more. When I click on the link to load the login page or directly type in the login url, all background images are visible, its only happening when I refresh (F5) the login page, both in IE and FF.

1. Cleared FF cache
2. Browse to the login url (https://domain/login/): style.css (status 200) and all bg images are visible (status 200)
3. Browse again to the login url: style.css (status 200) and all bg images are visible (status 200) but no trace of them in firebug (loaded from cache)
4. Press F5: style.css (status 304) and all the bg images that are visible have status 304 except one bg image that is not shown, has the status 200 and size is 0
5. Press F5 again: style.css loaded (status 304) and all the bg images that are visible have status 304 except one bg image that is not shown, has status 200 and size is 0 (its not the same as the previous one, that one is now shown with status 304)

The strange part is that the missing bg image has status 200 (no cache?) in firebug and Fiddler returns "HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure" on the missing bg image. Another weird thing is, when i put `<img src="/assets/images/icon_cart.png" />` directly in the login.php file, that image is allways loaded

The background images, style.css and login.php are located in the private_html directory and have https as protocol. SSL Certificate is corectly installed.
I don’t know where to look anymore for the problem (I did try different headers, cleared cache, tested local & on a public server, stripped the login.php file) i think its something small, but i'm lost right now